# A wildcard is said to import all classes in a package. "It doesn't import child packages, fields, or methods." What does this mean?

Tags: java, java-8

In the **Sybex** book, ***OCA Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer I - Study Guide***, page **10** of Chapter **1** states the following:

> The * is a wildcard that matches all classes in the package. Every
>   class in the java.util package is available to this program when Java
>   compiles it. **It doesn’t import child packages, fields, or methods; it
>   imports only classes.** (Okay, it’s only classes for now, but there’s a
>   special type of import called the “static import” that imports other
>   types. You’ll learn more about that in Chapter 4.)

It was my naive understanding that since a class contains members (fields and methods), it is implied that those are imported, as well. However, according to the author of this book, it appears that the situation is more caveated.

If you are importing a class, and you don't have access to the members of that class, then what is the point of importing that class?

Comment: It says "Every class in the java.util package is available", meaning for full use by the class's simple name. It  says nothing about access. Imports do not affect access, only the name in the source code.

Comment: @EbonyMaw the imports (static or plain) are just for you. The compiler will sill use the fully qualified classes names everywhere.

Comment: Then for java.lang.* you would have trouble with Integer.MAX_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE btw this example for class variables for instance variables you use new keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the point of importing that class?

Imagine that you do not import classes inside `java.util`. If you want to create a `Map` you type:

```
java.util.Map<String, Integer> myMap = new java.util.HashMap<>();
```

If you import the class in that package like `import java.util.*;`:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

> If you are importing a class, and you don't have access to the members
>   of that class

Imports do nothing with access, they are all about readability and convenience. You don't have to type that much and the second declaration is much more readable, but you can use the same methods of `myMap` in both cases.

---

The `static import` that the book mentions (from the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)):

> The static import declaration is analogous to the normal import
>   declaration. Where the normal import declaration imports classes from
>   packages, allowing them to be used without package qualification, the
>   static import declaration imports static members from classes,
>   allowing them to be used without class qualification.

A good example for static import is the usage of `Mockito` in unit tests. Without any imports you can verify some behavior like:

```
org.mockito.Mockito.verify(mock, org.mockito.Mockito.never()).someMethod();
```

If you use normal import `import org.mockito.Mockito;`:

```
Mockito.verify(mock, Mockito.never()).someMethod();
```

and with static import `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;` you can type

```
verify(mock, never()).someMethod();
```

Here the `verify` and `never` **static** methods can be used even without specifying their class (`Mockito`).

Answer (score 2):

> If you are importing a class, and you don't have access to the members of that class, then what is the point of importing that class?

Suppose you have a package `com.ebony.maw.utils`, and that package has a class `MyUtilities`, and the class has a static method `findFizgigs()`.  If you say

```
import com.ebony.maw.utils.*;
```

you can now say

```
MyUtilities.findFizgigs("thingy-002");
```

instead of having to say

```
com.ebony.maw.utils.MyUtilities.findFizgigs("thingy-002");
```

But you still can't say

```
findFizgigs("thingy-002");
```

without the class name.  That's what they mean by importing the class, but not importing the method.  It just means you can use the class name without having to supply a package name prefix.  But you can still use the method--you just have to supply the class name as a prefix.

Comment: Ahh... so that's what they were trying to say!  :)
Great step-by-step explanation!